# how download link in vps from net ( with web appliction )?

Tags: download-manager, web-application, vps

I have vps and i want download link from net like rapid share ( with account ) or from direct link or also torrent...

is there any web application with php or python to download link form net?

edit:

i want have application with php or python and install it on vps ... and use it with address like http://ip/x.php and add link to this web application and then this application download it to vps.

Comment: Could you clarify your question please? What exactly are you aiming to do? Do you want to feed an application on your vps urls for it to download? [FYI I noticed your closed question.](http://superuser.com/questions/270977/how-can-i-download-a-file-directly-to-a-web-server-with-web-application-closed)

Answer (score 0):

You may fetch files from the net using:

1. wget http://example.org/pub/doc/howto.html
2. curl http://ex.com/file2 > file.bin
3. netcat server.org 80 <<ENTER>> GET /path/to/file.txt